# How to implement IP whitelist correctly on Apache 2.4?

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, google-cloud-platform

I've a website (running on CentOS at Google Cloud, Apache 2.4.37), say it's name is awesomesite.co.id.

There are certain pages on that website, e.g awesomesite.co.id/dev123/secret.html which is not supposed to be accessible from any network, except from whitelisted IPs. So here's what I already did:

1. Edited `/etc/httpd/conf.d/awesome-site.conf`. I put 2 whitelisted IPs on it.

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName awesomesite.co.id
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/awesome
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/awesome-site-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/awesome-site-requests.log combined
    #commented for testing PHP proxy, allow both http and https work
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =awesomesite.co.id
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
    </VirtualHost>
    
    <Directory /dev123/*>
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 123.123.100.100
            Allow from 200.200.44.59
    </Directory>
```

2. Restarted Apache: `systemctl restart http.service`

I tried to access awesomesite.co.id/dev123/secret.html on a few mobile devices (all different telco providers). The result is all devices could accessed that page normally.

So what's the correct way, then?

Answer (score 5):

The `Allow`, `Deny`, and `Order` directives, provided by mod_access_compat, are deprecated as of version 2.4 and will no longer work.

Use `Require` instead:

```
Require ip 123.123.100.100
Require ip 200.200.44.59
```

The `Require` directive is provided by the `mod_authz_host` module.

More infirmation can be found in the [Apache HTTP Server documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html#host)

Note that a [CIDR range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) such as `Require ip 200.200.44.0/24` is possible as well (see [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html#reqip) for more examples):

> In the second form, ip.address is an IP address, a partial IP address, a network/netmask pair, or a network/nnn CIDR specification. Either IPv4 or IPv6 addresses may be used.

Comment: Can we Require a specific IP range, such as `Require 11.22.33.0/24`? I didn't find it in the doc, but another post seemed to say it works, without real confirmation. Any idea @digijay?

Comment: Yes, a CIDR address should work, [see the apache2 doc here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html#host)

Comment: Thanks @digijay, I added this information in your answer for future reference.